# Wait for response with $.getJSON()

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm (trying to) using JSON with PHP.

I want to plot a graph using this plugin: http://www.jqplot.com
The problem is: It's being plot before the new data arrives. Is there anyway to make jQuery wait for the $.getJSON() and the plot it?

`myArray` and `title` are the new data that will be used later.

```
$.getJSON('./ajax/refreshData.php', function(data) {
    myArray = data.arrayName;
    newTitle = data.newTitle;
});

plot1 = $.jqplot('divname', [ myArray ], {
    series : [ {
    renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer} ],
    title : newTitle,
```

...

Comment: move the assignment of plot1 into the callback where myArray is assigned the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('./ajax/refreshData.php', function(data) {
    myArray = data.arrayName;
    newTitle = data.newTitle;
    plot1 = $.jqplot('divname', [ myArray ], {
       series : [ {
       renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer} ],
       title : newTitle,
});
```